# Java Universal tween Engine or ObjectAnimator for Android

Tags: android, animation

I came to know about Java Universal Tween [Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)  after seeing the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aurelienribon.tweenengine.demo&hl=en).  And the demo app produced some "wow" kind of Animations and also looked promising. But i haven't seen its docs. I read about ObjectAnimator and it is simple to use for common animations like Alpha, Linear, angular.

Please help me in choosing between "objectAnimator" or Java Universal Tween Engine for android App development as i have to do some complex Animations with better performance.  And please share any known issues that you came cross while using Java Universal tween Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I won't be able to answer objectively since I made the Tween Engine, but I may provide some hints to let you choose.

Actually, ObjectAnimator may be more easy to use if you want to start directly with simple animations. It has decent performances and will work out-of-the-box.

The Tween Engine supports powerful things like sequences of multiple animations, speed control of the animations, repetitions, yoyo playing, callbacks and much more. However, the fact it is generic requires you to tell it how to access the attributes of your objects (their position, opacity, rotation, etc). The good thing is that you are able to animate every possible attribute of every possible object, not just Views and Drawables. Since the Tween Engine is "Universal", it can be reused to animate your other projects (games, UIs, etc) as long as they are written in Java (they don't have to be related to android). Therefore, the engine is "learn once, reuse anywhere". In fact, the engine is being ported to C# and C++, so you can really reuse it anywhere :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please brief out on UI-performance between Tween Engine and Object Animator?

Comment: Well, the Tween Engine was designed for games. Therefore, it aims at providing the best possible performances. No runtime allocation, no garbadge collector. Every objects are reused over time, and the memory footprint is as low as possible. Therefore, it should help UI animations being really smooth.